# Changing between 2 python kernels in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, cmd, version-control, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I have two python versions of python 3.7 and 3.9. I want to run python 3.7 and python 3.7 separately on jupyter notebook as different kernels. I want to swap between the kernels how would I be able to assign that. I have jupyter notebook installed on both versions of python.

```
c:\user>py -3.7
c:\user.py -3.9
```

Answer (score 0):

To install a kernel, use the following command in the Python environment you want to install.  If using a virtual environment, activate it, otherwise run the "ipython.exe" in the Scripts directory of your installation.  `--user` not required for an "all users" installation:

```
ipython kernel install --name "<kernel-name>" --user
```

To remove:

```
jupyter kernelspec remove <kernel-name>
```

To rename, user the following to get the paths where the kernals are located:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

Open the `kernel.json` file in the appropriate directory and edit `display_name`.

Helpful links:

- https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html
- https://queirozf.com/entries/jupyter-kernels-how-to-add-change-remove